# Checking if a linked list is a palindrome

Tags: c++, linked-list, palindrome

I am stuck in a question where I have to make a function to check if the given linked list is palindrome.

Here is my approach for the problem, this is failing in the test case (1->1->2->1) the question is to check if the given linked list is palindromic or not.

```cpp
ListNode* reverse(ListNode* head)
{
    ListNode* c = head;
    ListNode* p = NULL;
    ListNode* n;
    while (c != NULL) {
        n = c->next;
        c->next = p;
        p = c;
        c = n;
    }
    head = p;
    return head;
}

class Solution {
public:
    bool isPalindrome(ListNode* head)
    {
        if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL)
            return true;
        ListNode* temp = NULL;
        temp = reverse(head);
        int flag = 0;
        while (temp != NULL && head != NULL) {
            if (temp->val != head->val) {
                flag = 1;
            }
            head = head->next;
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        if (flag == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Your `reverse` function mutates the original list, so you cannot iterate over both lists.

Comment: This looks like some competitive programing problem. Can you provide a link?

Comment: Which are the constraints? Does `ListNode` have previous node?

Comment: There are already a few questioni on SO on the topic. One of them might answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcpp%5D+linked+list+palindrome

Answer (score 0):

The `reverse(ListNode* head)` reverses the **same** linked list to `1->2->1->1`.

The `head` is pointing to the last node `1`, whereas the `temp` points to the first `1`.

In code, we were trying to compare the two linked list with starting node `temp` and `head` and since those are not equal the code gives a wrong answer.